# how to get the bytes count of unsigned char datatype in iphonesdk

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode

Wrote below code... How can i get the count of bytes in bytePtr variable.

```
unsigned char *bytePtr = (unsigned char *)[imageData bytes];
```

Thanks.....in advance

Answer (score 2):

the number of bytes is given by `[ imageData length ]`

Answer (score 1):

either use 
<strike>strlen(bytePtr);</strike> or use `[imageData length];`

Edited on the request of to Mr. Jeremy as he suggested. But I want to add more on that, it might not be terminated by the `NULL` but data may contain `0` value which will act as a null terminator so the string after that is not counted, So it's a Bad idea. use `[imageData length];`

Comment: Second answer is correct.  First answer is completely wrong (bytes of an NSData are not guaranteed to be null terminated).  I'll remove my down vote if you edit it out.

Comment: There is no question.  The bytes is not a C string particularly if they are the bytes of an image.  Removed down vote

Answer (score 1):

See the Documentation for [NSDate](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSData_Class/Reference/Reference.html) ,

where **length** return the "The number of bytes contained in the receiver."

```
- (NSUInteger)length
```

So use

```
int numberOFByte = [ imageData length ];
```

Comment: Same comment as for Inder Kumar Rathore

Comment: No problem.  I've removed the down vote to reflect your edit.